# Previewable email templates token replacement

Tags: tokens

From my form_alter code, I would like to redirect to email template (Previewable email templates)

```
$form_state['redirect'] = url('pet/email_template', $options ) 
The params are set as 
$options = array(
      'absolute' => TRUE,
      'query' => array('nid' => '1','uid' => '3')
  );
```

In the email template, there are tokens [webform:sid] and [webform:data]. How do I replace those data [webform:??] by using the url call to template?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the token [webform:sid] in template

Use
function mymodule_pet_substitutions_alter(&$substitutions, $params) {
$substitutions['webform'] = array('sid'=> {value});
}